# Переадресация https на http на 1 папку

Tags: .htaccess, https, redirect

Привет, 
Прошу помощи, перерыл весь интернет, не нашел реализации.
Весь сайт переадресуется на https, но надо для папки и всех последующих ID отменить переадресацию.
Реализовано посредством .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/items/item$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Но для site.com/items/item/id все-равно работает https
Где может быть ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/items/item.*
```